# git clone error: RPC failed; curl 52 GnuTLS recv error (-110)

Tags: git, ssl, github

Since couple days I am facing this issue with git clone,
I also went though similar issues on stackoverflow which didn't solve this issue.
Firewall is also not present in my system.
Any input on this or debug this issue will be useful.

Example while cloning the apache mesos logs (export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 used)

```
# git clone https://github.com/apache/mesos.git
Cloning into 'mesos'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 140.82.113.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (140.82.113.3) port 443 (#0)
* found 129 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 387 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: github.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: EC/ECDSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=GitHub\, Inc.,CN=github.com
*        start date: Thu, 25 Mar 2021 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: Wed, 30 Mar 2022 23:59:59 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert\, Inc.,CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /apache/mesos.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: git/2.17.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; sandbox
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: 875F:027E:2B3997:E007E0:607E954A
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
<
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host github.com: 0x2aa0aa414f0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host github.com
* Connected to github.com (140.82.113.3) port 443 (#0)
> POST /apache/mesos.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: git/2.17.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 5713

* upload completely sent off: 5713 out of 5713 bytes
* GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
* Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/apache/mesos.git/git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 140.82.113.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (140.82.113.4) port 443 (#1)
* found 129 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 387 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: github.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: EC/ECDSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=GitHub\, Inc.,CN=github.com
*        start date: Thu, 25 Mar 2021 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: Wed, 30 Mar 2022 23:59:59 GMT
*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert\, Inc.,CN=DigiCert High Assurance TLS Hybrid ECC SHA256 2020 CA1
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> POST /apache/mesos.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: git/2.17.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 5713
* upload completely sent off: 5713 out of 5713 bytes
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
error: RPC failed; curl 52 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening with any other repo?

I did have this error before and I recompiled git to get it working again

here's some of the steps I took

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev -y
sudo apt-get build-dep git -y
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
cd ~
mkdir source-git
cd source-git/
apt-get source git
cd git-2.*.*/
sed -i -- 's/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/libcurl4-openssl-dev/' ./debian/control
sed -i -- '/TEST\s*=\s*test/d' ./debian/rules
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../git_*ubuntu*.deb
```

Not using -y is ok, -y is just for skip inputting y. The result is:

```
└> $ git clone https://github.com/apache/mesos.git
Cloning into 'mesos'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 174856, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 174856 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 174851
Receiving objects: 100% (174856/174856), 394.38 MiB | 15.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (130737/130737), done.
```

Comment: the mesos cloned successfully.  git clone https://github.com/jnr/jffi.git
Cloning into 'jffi'...
error: RPC failed; curl 52 Empty reply from server
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: it seems you are experiencing issues while cloning using HTTP(S) protocol. That said, you could:

1)

# Linux
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

# Windows
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
 
git clone &lt;YOUR CLONE URL&gt;

or you can try attempt on increasing the buffer size

2) attempt on increasing the buffer size

git config http.postBuffer &lt;SIZE&gt;

Comment: using ubuntu 18.04 system. http.postbuffer=524288000, yet facing issue ```* upload completely sent off: 1560 out of 1560 bytes
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
error: RPC failed; curl 52 Empty reply from server
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly```

Comment: Give this a go 
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400

Comment: It is a network issue , it is resolved now.